# Error changing nested ViewModel to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create a nested ViewModel and have managed to confuse myself, I don't think the approach that I'm following is correct (also it doesn't work), so I'm hoping for some guidance.

Firstly I have a Quote Item that looks like this:

```
public class Quote
{

    public Quote()
    {
        this.QuoteItems = new HashSet<QuoteItem>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int QuoteID { get; set; }

    // Other properties not shown

    public ICollection<QuoteItem> QuoteItems { get; set; }
}
```

A quote has many QuoteItems:

```
public class QuoteItem
{

    [Key]
    public int QuoteItemID { get; set; }

    // Other properties not shown

    public Quote Quote { get; set; }
}
```

My Quote Controller uses a ViewModel called QuoteFormViewModel mainly to strongly type some drop down lists:

```
public class QuoteFormViewModel
{
    public Quote Quote { get; set; }

    public QuoteItemViewModel QuoteItemViewModel { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ConstructionTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ConditionTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DesignTypes { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
 QuoteFormViewModel viewModel = createViewModel(new Quote());

 viewModel.Quote.QuoteItems.Add(new QuoteItem());
```

In my view model you'll see I have a viewModel for my QuoteItems called QuoteItemViewModel, this is because I have an EditorFor for QuoteItems which I add to the Create and Edit forms:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Quote.QuoteItems)
```

The other reason I use QuoteItemViewModel is because a quote item will need strongly typed drop down lists as well.

My problem is that this works well but only if I add a single quote item.  What I feel I need to do is in my QuoteFormViewModel change

```
public QuoteItemViewModel QuoteItemViewModel { get; set; }
```

to

```
public IEnumerable<QuoteItemViewModel> QuoteItemViewModels { get; set; }
```

But in my controller I cannot add additional items - the following code doesn't work:

```
viewModel.QuoteItemViewModels.Add  // Add doesn't work here...
```

Also on post my QuoteItems are in their seperate viewmodel, rather than added to Quote - do I need to do this manually or is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add items to a `IEnumerable`. You can however add items to a `List`.

```
public List<QuoteItemViewModel> QuoteItemViewModels { get; set; }
```

Even better is to use the `interface`:

```
public ICollection<QuoteItemViewModel> QuoteItemViewModels { get; set; }
```

Or you can convert your `IEnumerable` to a `List` with LINQ:

```
this.QuoteItemViewModels.ToList().Add(item);
```

[Some more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20160968/2478357)

Comment: Changing to an ICollection seems to be the best result here - do I need to change @Html.EditorFor(x => x.QuoteItemViewModels)?

Comment: @Evonet To show all your items in your view, you have to iterate over them. So use a `foreach` in your code.
Also, you have to initialize the `ICollection` before you can add items: `this.QuoteItemViewModels = new List<QuoteItemViewModels>();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast your `IEnumerable` to `List` in order to add items to your collection:

```
viewModel.Quote.QuoteItems.ToList().Add(new QuoteItem());
```